# Lower sum/Riemann Integral

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $c>0$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x \in[0,c]$ .  Let $P$={$x_0,x_1,...x_n$} be a partition of $[0,c]$ where $x_i=\frac{i}{n}c$ for $i=0,1,2,...n$

How do you find $L(P,f)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} L(P,f)$ ?

Comment: Where are you having trouble applying the definition of $L(P, f)$? Note that $f$ is a strictly increasing function, so its minimum on an interval is....

Comment: so it's minimum on the interval (x_i,x_i+1) is x_i=ic/n, the length of any interval is c/n so the sum is [0+c/n+2c/n+..+(n-1)c/n]*c/n right?

Answer (score 0):

As you've identified, the minimum value of $f$ on the interval $[x_i, x_{i + 1}]$ is $x_i$. Hence $L(P, f)$ is given by

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} \min_{[x_i, x_{i + 1}]} f(x) \cdot (x_{i + 1} - x_i) &= \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} x_i \cdot (x_{i + 1} - x_i) \\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{i c}{n} \cdot \left(\frac{(i + 1)c}{n} - \frac{i}{n}\right) \\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{ic^2}{n} \\
&= \frac{c^2}{n} \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} i
\end{align*}

Now this sum can be [computed explicitly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), and by taking a limit you'll get the Calc I answer of $c^2 / 2$.

Comment: Thanks man, just needed to see that worked out.